# What is the procedure to buy a motorcycle in Mexico as Indian citizen?

Tags: indian-citizens, mexico

I will be traveling to Mexico City some time around this year as a Indian citizen with work visa. I am planning to buy a new motor cycle for my commute and exploring in and around Mexico with the motorcycle. What is the procedure to buy a new motorcycle in Mexico City, and what are the documents and proofs needed for an Indian citizen as per my need?